# operator overloading in templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use std::find algorithm & my third argument is object of type MyPair that has overloaded == operator. But the problem is its not getting called. Here is my code:

MyPair.h

```
template<class K, class V> class MyPair;

template<class K,class V> 
bool operator==(const MyPair<K,V>& p1, const MyPair<K,V>& p2);

template<class K,class V>
class MyPair:public std::pair<K,V>
{
public:
    MyPair(){};

    MyPair(const K&x, const V& y) :pair<K, V>(x, y){ cout << "ctor"<< endl; }

    template<class K, class V>
    friend bool operator==<>(const MyPair<K, V>& p1, const MyPair<K, V>& p2) { 
           cout<<"called"; return true; }
};
```

another file I am using `std::find` algo

```
void WordVector::insert(string word){
    MyPair<string, int> p(word, 1);
    auto iter = find(wordvec.begin(),wordvec.end(),p);

    if (iter == wordvec.end()){
        wordvec.push_back(p);
    }
    else{
        ++iter->second;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you deriving from `std::pair`?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile with my GCC.

Comment: Actually I am using vector<pair<string,int>> in my wordvector class to store words & their frequencies as ints from a text file. Now in order to do comparison of string words, I am deriving pair class & overloading == operator to do just comparison of string words & not int value.

Comment: My code is getting compiled properly but the only problem is ==operator is not getting called, where I can do something like this:
return p1.first==p2.first;

Comment: I have tried everything like forward declaration and stuff but still no idea y its not working. anyone???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me with `g++ 4.8.3`:

EDIT: To declare `operator ==` and define it right afterwards was pretty senseless. Therefore, I shifted the definition of the operator behind the definition of `MyPair`. Also this works with `g++`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<class K, class V> class MyPair;

template<class K,class V> 
bool operator==(const MyPair<K,V>& p1, const MyPair<K,V>& p2);

template<class K,class V>
class MyPair:public std::pair<K,V>
{
public:
    MyPair(){};

    MyPair(const K&x, const V& y) : std::pair<K, V>(x, y){ std::cout << "ctor\n"; }

    friend bool operator==<>(const MyPair<K, V>& p1, const MyPair<K, V>& p2);
};

template <class K, class V>
bool operator==(const MyPair<K, V>& p1, const MyPair<K, V>& p2) { 
    std::cout<<"called"; return true;
}

//another file I am using std::find algo
class WordVector {
    std::vector<MyPair<std::string,int> > wordvec;
public:
    void insert(const std::string& word);
};

void WordVector::insert(const std::string& word){
    MyPair<std::string, int> p(word, 1);
    auto iter = find(wordvec.begin(),wordvec.end(),p);

    if (iter == wordvec.end()){
        wordvec.push_back(p);
    }
    else{
        ++iter->second;

    }
}

int main() {
    WordVector wv;

    wv.insert("first");
    wv.insert("second");


    return 0;
}


/**
     Local Variables:
     compile-command: "g++ -std=c++11 test.cc -o test.exe && ./test.exe"
     End:
 */
```

The output is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cc -o test.exe && ./test.exe
ctor
ctor
called
Compilation finished at Sat Aug  9 18:31:36
```

With the modification

```
template<class K,class V>
class MyPair:public std::pair<K,V>
{
public:
    MyPair(){};

    MyPair(const K&x, const V& y) : std::pair<K, V>(x, y){ std::cout << "ctor\n"; }

    template<class K, class V>
    friend bool operator==<>(const MyPair<K, V>& p1, const MyPair<K, V>& p2) { 
        std::cout<<"called"; return true; }

};
```

which fits better the original I get the following error messages and warnings:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cc -o test.exe && ./test.exe
test.cc:19:12: error: declaration of 'class K'
  template <class K, class V>
            ^
test.cc:11:10: error:  shadows template parm 'class K'
 template<class K,class V>
          ^
test.cc:19:21: error: declaration of 'class V'
  template <class K, class V>
                     ^
test.cc:11:18: error:  shadows template parm 'class V'
 template<class K,class V>
                  ^
test.cc:20:73: error: defining explicit specialization 'operator==<>' in friend declaration
  friend bool operator==<>(const MyPair<K, V>& p1, const MyPair<K, V>& p2)
                                                                         ^

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sat Aug  9 18:37:40
```

which are quite descriptive.

Comment: I tried this but still not working. == operator is not getting called.

Comment: Maybe, this is a compiler issue? You should add to your question what compiler you are using. Did you directly test the program from the answer above or did you try to fix your code?

Comment: oh when I copied ur whole code in new file & copied all of it within the same file, then its working! Can you tell me what could be the problem possibly.I am not using .cpp file. Just MyPair.h file

Comment: Considering the error messages in my answer it is surprising that your original code compiled. Whether the code from my answer works or not does not depend on the fact that it is contained in one `cpp`-file or split into a header and a `cpp`-file. It is difficult to deduce what goes wrong in your code without knowing a minimal example for your problem. You need to construct such a minimal compiling example showing the problem. It is very likely that you find the solution for the problem yourself on this path. Otherwise you can post the minimal example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to find some specific pair why not just use [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with an appropriate predicate ?

E.g ([demo](http://ideone.com/tXToOz)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<pair<int,int> > a = { {1,1} , {1,2}, {1,3}};

    auto res = find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), 
                    [](pair<int,int> p){ return (p.first == 1 && p.second==3);});
    cout<< (*res).first;
    return 0;
}
```